# Animation Query In Android

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I have an activity in my android app, which has an arrangement of 3x3 matrix of Image buttons occupying the entire page. When clicked on any one of the buttons it loads a new activity.
Basically its an logo quiz type application, so the 9 image buttons represent 9 levels and clicking on each level opens up many logos.
I want that when we click on any of the image buttons, all the image buttons should turn around 180 degree and  fade out to open load the new activity.

http://s1366.photobucket.com/user/kevindesai777/slideshow/

If there is a way to animate, just help me, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [View.animate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#animate%28%29) in your Buttons to create the desired animation.
You can the use [ViewPropertyAnimator.rotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#rotation%28float%29) to animate the rotation of the View.